# ClientCertificateRequested and BasicAuthenticationRequested in Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, webview2

To avoid prompts from the embedded browser widgets I have to use the WebView2 events ClientCertificateRequested and BasicAuthenticationRequested in my WinForms application. After a few hours of testing I've managed to get it working by using the underlaying object CoreWebView2 instead of the control directly. Are there plans to expose these events in the namespace Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms in the same way as other events?

The events are undefined for WinForms WebView2 controls (the environment: VS 2022, .NET 7.0, WebView2 1.0.2045.28 from NuGet).
I have used the underlaying object by doing this:

```
    webBrowser.CoreWebView2.ClientCertificateRequested += webView_ClientCertificateRequested;
    webBrowser.CoreWebView2.BasicAuthenticationRequested += webView_BasicAuthenticationRequested;

...

        void webView_BasicAuthenticationRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2BasicAuthenticationRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("webView_BasicAuthenticationRequested");
            args.Response.UserName = "xxx";
            args.Response.Password = "yyy";
        }

        void webView_ClientCertificateRequested(object sender, CoreWebView2ClientCertificateRequestedEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("webView_ClientCertificateRequested");
            IReadOnlyList<CoreWebView2ClientCertificate> certificateList = args.MutuallyTrustedCertificates;
            ...
        }
```

Comment: *That does not work*: ?? meaning? -- CoreWebView2 is initialized (not `null`) after you have called `await [WebView2].EnsureCoreWebView2Async()`. The `[WebView2]` object is not null after `InitializeComponents()` is called -- You need a 105.0.1298.0+ runtime

Comment: @Jimi, what do you mean with 105.0.1298.0? I'm using WebView2 1.0.2045.28 from NuGet.

Comment: Have to apologize for the misleading statement that CoreWebView2 is not null only after the form has been shown. That is true in my case because I'm invoking EnsureCoreWebView2Async in the form_Shown event ... Will correct the original question.

Comment: That's the WebView2 version, I meant the [Runtime version](https://developer.microsoft.com/it-it/microsoft-edge/webview2/) -- You haven't said what is not working, what you tested this on and whether you have tested the same (whatever that is) in a WPF app

Comment: I've managed to get it working and have updated the post accordingly. I have had a typo in my code which caused bypassing the debug print ...

Comment: @Jimi, thanks for the follow on. Though, I do not understand what do you mean with "Runtime version" and the link to https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/. I have never used that download - WebView2 is fully under the control of NuGet, and I have only installed WebView2 1.0.2045.28 from there. It obviously includes all needed runtime DLLs. The properties of Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll also show that the level is 1.0.2045.28.

Comment: The NuGet package does not install the runtime, just the loader (`WebView2Loader.dll`). You can check the Runtime version of WebView2 in `Programs and Features` (Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime). It's a System feature. Once installed, in Windows 10+, it should automatically update. But better verify. I also have posted a link to the Runtime download page, in case it's needed

Comment: @Jimi, thanks once again. It is 117.0.2045.47 (installed 3 days ago). I'm out of the woods now ...